# Vue router return an error in mounted hook

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I have an error with Vue-Router, when click to the route-link component wasn't loaded.

> [Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook (Promise/async): "TypeError: Cannot read properties of >undefined (reading 'id')"
> found in
>  at assets/organisms/manage/ManageWorkFlowOverview.vue

Do you have an idea of the origin of the problem ?

Thanks in advance.

Best regards,
Jérémy

Comment: The question lacks https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . The idea is that the origin in the problem is in code that the error refers to, which isn't shown

Comment: in ManageWorkFlowOverview.vue component, somewhere you are reading id propery of something.  which is still undefine. i assueme that you want id propery from data return by your request. you should use 'await' for response.